# Simple example of a Heuristic proof method

Tags: proof-writing

of all the proof methods I had never seen the Heuristic proof method before, I came across this http://oddperfect.org/pomerance.html , seemed too complicated to be used for understanding the method itself, proof by contradiction uses irrationality of square root of 2 as an example, so every other method of proof has a simple example to understand the method, what is a simple example for Heuristic proof? is there a list of proof methods and some simple examples/applications?

Comment: I think you're confused.  A heuristic argument such as this is not a proof.

Comment: @RobertIsrael : Is there such a thing as heuristic proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example for the Twin Primes conjecture.  The Prime Number Theorem can be viewed as saying that the "probability" that a positive integer $n$ is prime is approximately $1/\log(n)$.  Assuming independence, this would make the probability that $n$ and $n+2$ are both prime approximately $1/\log(n)^2$.  Since $\sum_{n=2}^\infty 1/\log(n)^2 = \infty$, that would indicate that there should be infinitely many twin primes.

Of course, this is **not** a proof, and can't be made into a proof as far as we know: Twin Primes is still a conjecture!